# Why is the output,"Error in if (set[i]%%j == 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Tags: r, primes, modulus

The code block is printing prime numbers in a vector. The language is R. The code is:

```
count=0
 set<-60:75
 for (i in 1:16){
   count=0
   for (j in 2:i-1){
     if(set[i]%%j==0){
       
       count=count+1
     }
   }
   if (count == 0){
     Print(set[i]+"is Prime")}
   else {
       Print(set[i]+" is not Prime")}
 }
```

Comment: Which programming language is this? In most languages the modulus operator is `%` not `%%`.

Comment: @Guy Incognito edited the title. It's R